# Android video test automation

Tags: android, testing, video

I want to automate testing the video player on *Android ICS-x86*. Basically, I am starting off with functions like *play, pause, random seek, shuffle*.

Please tell me good tools which I can use for that.

*MonkeyRunner* is there, but it doesn't support all *Python* modules. So, I am looking for more tools and ways for automation.

Comment: was you able to solve your problem?